# Why does the content of the sent email contain session information

Tags: java, email

The following is the full content of the email ：

[Content of my email ....] smtp.aliyun-inc.com MX AliMail Server

AUTH LOGIN

amFydmlzQGJhbmdkYW8tdGVjaC5jb20=

WkNfamlhd2Vpc2k=
MAIL FROM:jarvis@bangdao-tech.com

RCPT TO:jie.sha@bangdao-tech.com

DATA

=============

Q:How to remove the session information above

YML:

```yaml
  mail:
    host: host
    port: 465
    username: email
    password: password
    default-encoding: utf-8
    properties:
      mail:
        debug: true
        smtp:
          ssl:
            trust: [smtp server]
            enable: true
          allow8bitmime: true
          socketFactoryClass: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
            required: true
```

code:

```java
@Component
public class EmailHelper {
    @Autowired
    JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    private static JavaMailSender _javaMailSender;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        this._javaMailSender=javaMailSender;
    }
    public static void simpleEmail(String from, String to,String content,String subject) {
        SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setText(content);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setFrom(from);
        msg.setTo(to);
        _javaMailSender.send(msg);
    }

}
```

Maven:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: To rule out the obvious thing: are you sure your "content" variable doesn't have this already in it, by the time you call your emailSender?

Comment: @moilejter yes, and i think  the session inormation come from  telnet communication, but I don't know what caused  this message appear in content of mail